# how to link a page in spring mvc

Tags: html, jsp, spring-mvc

Hello, I am working on spring mvc and I have in my home page a a simple link of page register and the register.jsp is contained in my WEB-INF/pages/register.jsp

So on my index.jsp which is in my base folder means in webcontent parllel to WEB-INF so how can i link this register.jsp

```
<li class="float-block" style="margin-left:50px;"><a href="pages/register.jsp" class="login" title="New User Register here" >Register</a></li>
```

Please suggest me how to do this to run this link

Comment: please suggest me any answer plzzz

Comment: Please suggest me how to do this to run this link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that by redirecting it to a controller and then to the jsp of your need.

Check [this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_page_redirection_example.htm).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your configuration. Check request mapping in your controller class and all xml configurations.
Normally it should be something like `<a href="/register">` depends on the controller.

Answer (score 0):

a href tag name and request mapping of controller class address should be same and add  the object of that class  in Form Tag like